# setState() doesn't refresh my widget tree when using dynamic data to build the page

Tags: flutter

I'm using the latest version of Flutter and I have a problem that I don't understand. Here is the situation: I build a dropdown button according to the value of a variable. That variable might change via setState() when changing the value of the dropdown.

Code example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const DynamicWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class DynamicWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DynamicWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DynamicWidgetState createState() => _DynamicWidgetState();
}

class _DynamicWidgetState extends State<DynamicWidget> {
  List<Map<String, String>> data = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // after a condition here, data can become this:
    // **NOTE**: data will never have the same length
    data = [
      {"name": 'c', "unit": "cm"}
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text('An example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // a few things there
          // ...
          // here, that text will never change despite "setState()"
          Text(data.toString()),
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            itemBuilder: (_, int i) {
              return Row(
                children: [
                  Text("Unit for ${data[i]['name']} :"),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  DropdownButton(
                    elevation: 0,
                    value: data[i]['unit'],
                    onChanged: (String? newUnit) {
                      setState(() {
                        // doesn't change anything
                        data[i]['unit'] = newUnit!;
                        // however the new value is printed correctly
                        print("data = $data");
                      });
                    },
                    underline: Container(height: 2, color: Colors.cyan),
                    items: ["km", "hm", "dam", "m", "dm", "cm", "mm"]
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                      (String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value),
                        );
                      },
                    ).toList(),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Basically I have some data that represent letters of a formula and their given unit (and that formula will change over time according to user's choices). I want to have a dropdown that lists the variables and allows the user to change the unit of these variables. I'm blocked because `setState()` doesn't do anything, it doesn't refresh the page, therefore the initial value given to the `DropdownButton` stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
data = [
  {"name": 'c', "unit": "cm"}
];
```

is executed every time the widget is rebuilt. So your `setState` works but whatever you set in `setState` is overidden by this code.

Declare `data` as `late final` so you don't accidentally reinitialize it as you did previously. And initialize `data` once in `initState`:

```
late final List<Map<String, String>> data;

...

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  data = [
    {"name": 'c', "unit": "cm"}
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` method will rebuild everything inside the build Widget, so if you're initializing your values ​​there, it will always stay in the initial item.

Here's an example of how to build a dropdown menu, either with predefined or asynchronous data:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  final _stageController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  var _stages = List<Stages>.empty(growable: true);

  var _dropdownMenuItems = List<DropdownMenuItem<Stages>>.empty(growable: true);

// you can define your data here 
  Stages _selectedStage = Stages(
    id: 20000,
    name: "Escolha",
    description: "Selecione",
    registration: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    // if you need to load async data
    loadStages();
    super.initState();
  }

  void loadStages() async {
    _stages.add(
      Stages(
        id: 1,
        name: "System",
        description: "description",
        registration: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      ),
    );

    try {
      // here load your data
      //StagesBloc stagesBloc = context.read<StagesBloc>();
      List<Stages> tempStages = await stagesBloc.getStages();
      setState(() {
        _stages = tempStages;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    _dropdownMenuItems = buildDropdownMenuItems(_stages);
    _selectedStage = _dropdownMenuItems[0].value!;
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<Stages>> buildDropdownMenuItems(List allStages) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<Stages>> items = [];
    for (Stages stage in allStages) {
      items.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: stage,
          child: Text(stage.name.toString()),
        ),
      );
    }
    return items;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: _body(),
    );
  }

  AppBar _buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF002d59),
      centerTitle: true,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Text(
        "SOME TEXT",
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: TextStyle(
          letterSpacing: 4,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container _body() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              if(_stages.isNotEmpty) _selectETAPA(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



  Container _selectETAPA() {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 25,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            "SOME TEXT HERE",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 15,
              letterSpacing: 2,
            ),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          DropdownButton(
            isExpanded: true,
            value: _selectedStage,
            items: _dropdownMenuItems,
            onChanged: (val) => setState(
              () {
                _selectedStage = val as Stages;
                _stageController.text = _selectedStage.name.toString();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```