# Flutter How to put all the Widgets into a List<Widget>?

Tags: flutter

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<int> _counters = [];
  List<Text> t = [];
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      for (var i = 0; i < _counters.length; i++) {
        _counters[i]++;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      _counters.add(i);
      t.add(Text('${_counters[i]}'));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: t,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to isolate the widget `List<Widget> t = [];`, but it doesn't work.  Because I want to change the a part of the UI when the date changed. It's similar to VUE. Any suggestion?Thanks!

Comment: [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69832551/setstate-doesnt-refresh-my-widget-tree-when-using-dynamic-data-to-build-the-p/69834391#69834391) to see whether it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you also need to call your `List<Widget>` in setState for rebuilding your widget

```
  int _counter = 2;
  List<Widget> t = [];
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      print("working $_counter");
      _counter++;
      t.add(Text('$_counter'));
    });
  }
```

Comment: if I t.add(Text('$_counter'));, the t widget will increase. I just want to show a _counter

Comment: @Alfred if you just want to show the counter what do you need `children: t` for?

Comment: For example, I receive the data(100 numbers) List<int> _counter = [12,32,43,45,...,100],I want to update the 100 Text(). I don't know how to do. Before, I used vue,

Comment: Before, I used vue,When I change the data, the widget would auto update. I have edited my code. Maybe it‘s more Close to reality. Thanks!

Comment: @Alfred so add your data to `List<int>` only (and not to `List<Widget>`) and based of that `List<int>` build your `Column` widget inside `build()` method - for example: `children: [..._counters.map((cnt) => Text('$cnt'))]` (or `children: _counters.map((cnt) => Text('$cnt')).toList()` if you dont like `...` spread operator)

Comment: @Alfred `[..._counters.map((cnt) => Text('$cnt'))]` - you have to add `...` spread operator or `_counters.map((cnt) => Text('$cnt')).toList()` if you dont like it

Comment: @Alfred sure, your welcome

Comment: *"you also need to call your List<Widget> in setState for rebuilding your widget"* - no, this is not true, you can change the state values and then call "empty" `setState(() {});` too

Comment: @pskink That means I must render all widget when change 1 number?

Comment: @Alfred if you have a huge number of counters then instead of `Column` check [Work with long lists](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists)